# How to notify bug (achievement dropdown does not show rep increase)?

Tags: bug

I had 60 rep increase on one SE site, but the achievement dropdown list shows only 10.

I found on Meta how to see the actual list of reputation changes (by clicking on the rep count below the picture in the profile page).
But the point is I still wanted to inform the staff about the existence of a BUG.

I used meta as it seems to be the only available mean. But I feel I am just cluttering the space. I do not need to ask a question: I know what to do for myself. I only want to inform the staff.

Comment: Several messages ... the point is, for bug reports, the system should look for most recent questions when listing possible duplicate after the title is given. Hence, we should be able to state first that it is a bug report.